# Mi grid-template-areas no aparece en el navegador como lo ordené en código

Tags: html5, css3

Sin importar el min-width en el que esté el media query, siempre me aparece a la derecha el el grid-area "link", a pesar de que en el grid-template-areas lo puse hasta abajo. ¿Cómo hago que aparezca abajo?

En el momento en que uso un media query para intentar hacerlo responsive con el tamaño de el navegador pero siempre se vuelve a estar el "link" a la derecha.

Llevo dos horas analizando el código y repasando mis apuntes pero no comprendo qué está mal con mi código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código CSS está correctamente, según he repasado durante dos hora.

```css
@media(min-width:1200px){
    #main{
      display:grid;
      grid-template-areas:
        "header header header header"
        "img-div img-div img-div section"
        "tribute_info tribute_info tribute_info tribute_info"
        "link link link link";
    }
    #header{
    display:grid;
     grid-area:header;

    }

    #title{
    text-align:center;
    }

    #title_description{
      text-align:center;
    }

    #img-div{
      display:grid;
      grid-area:img-div;
    }
    #image{
     align:center;
    }

    #img-caption{
      text-align:justify;
    }
    #section{
    display:grid;
    grid-area:section;
    }
    #tribute-info{
      display:grid;
      grid-area:article;
    }

    #tribute-link{
      display:grid;
      grid-area:link;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <main id="main">
    <div id="header">
      <h1 id="title">Porfirio Diaz<h1>
      <h2 id="title_description">Un padre duro</h2>
    </div>
    <img-div id="img-div">
      <img id="image" src="">
      <br />
      <figurecaption id="image_caption">Descripción</figurecaption>
    </img-div>
    <div id="section">
      <h2>Eventos importantes en los que participó</h2>
      <ul>
      <li>Exilio</li>
      <li>Tiene un desayuno en la parroquia</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tribute_info">
    <p><time>15 septiembre 1830</time> Nace el viejo bigotón<p>

    </div>
    <div id="tribute_link">
    <p>Para más información, revisa
    <a target="_blank" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porfirio_D%C3%ADaz">este link</a>
    </p>
     </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola, sube el código para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

Tenías varios errores tipográficos que he solucionado, pero el mayor de ellos era el siguiente:

**CSS**

```
#main {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "img-div img-div img-div section"
    "tribute_info tribute_info tribute_info tribute_info"
    "link link link link";
}

#tribute-info {
  display:grid;
  grid-area:article;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tribute_info">
```

En el `#main` has definido el área "tribute_info" pero al elemento que se supone que debería tenerlo le estás asignando `grid-area: article;` Esto ocasiona que ocupe solamente una de las celdas del grid en vez de las cuatro que estás buscando que ocupe.

Por otro lado tienes definido en el **HTML** un elemento `id="tribute_info"`, pero en el **CSS** haces referencia a un elemento `#tribute-info` ocasionando que sus reglas **CSS** no afecten a elemento alguno. Con el elemento `id="tribute_link` te está ocurriendo exactamente lo mismo.

```css
@media(min-width:1200px) {
  #main {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header header"
      "img-div img-div img-div section"
      "tribute_info tribute_info tribute_info tribute_info"
      "link link link link";
  }
  
  #header {
    display:grid;
    grid-area:header;
  }

  #title {
    text-align:center;
  }

  #title_description {
    text-align:center;
  }

  #img-div {
    display:grid;
    grid-area:img-div;
  }
  
  #image {
   text-align:center;
  }

  #img-caption {
    text-align:justify;
  }

  #section {
    display:grid;
    grid-area:section;
  }
  
  #tribute_info {
    display:grid;
    grid-area:tribute_info;
  }

  #tribute_link {
    display:grid;
    grid-area:link;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <main id="main">
    <div id="header">
      <h1 id="title">Porfirio Diaz</h1>
      <h2 id="title_description">Un padre duro</h2>
    </div>
    
    <img-div id="img-div">
      <img id="image" src="">
      <br />
      <figurecaption id="image_caption">Descripción</figurecaption>
    </img-div>
    
    <div id="section">
      <h2>Eventos importantes en los que participó</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Exilio</li>
        <li>Tiene un desayuno en la parroquia</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tribute_info">
      <p><time>15 septiembre 1830</time> Nace el viejo bigotón<p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tribute_link">
      <p>Para más información, revisa <a target="_blank" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porfirio_D%C3%ADaz">este link</a></p>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Eso resolvió la parte del ´article´ y del ´tribute_info´ pero al ejecutar en el navegador el código  el `tribute_link` sigue apareciendo a la derecha y no abajo, como se muestra en https://mefistocontreras.github.io/

Comment: Ya terminó en `@media(min-width:400px){
#main{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "img-div img-div"
    "section section"
    "tribute_info tribute_info"
    "tribute_link tribute_link";
}` Y a los otros le cambié su `grid-area` correspondiente.

Comment: Finamente lo quité de la grilla de main y lo volví un objeto independiente. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Si ejecutas mi solución y le das a "Página completa" para verlo a pantalla completa, verás que el `#tribute_link` se encuentra debajo de `#tribute_info`. Si inspeccionas los elementos con el inspector de tu navegador puedes ver las celdas que están ocupando, pudiendo verse que `#tribute_link` ocupa el 100% del grid. (las 4 columnas que has definido por fila). Si no te estaba funcionando es posible que otros elementos que no nos muestras estén entrando en juego.